# What does z stand for in vim?

Tags: key-bindings

I was looking up at tips on  screen shifting and came across the following tips:

```
zz = shift current line to middle of screen
zt = shift current line to top of screen
zb = shift current line to bottom of screen
```

My question is what is `z`?  What does it stand for? what other functionality might `z` have?

Comment: With folding, it can visually represent a ... folded sheet of paper. Otherwise, a letter that has to be used, after all good letters were taken for "important" operations that could use a good mnemonic.

Comment: My guess is that it stands for Zhift ;)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

z doesn't stand for anything.  g and z were two letters that went unused as standalone commands (`z<CR>`, `z.`, `z+`, `z-`, and `z^` existed) in vi, so they have been repurposed in Vim as a prefix for a variety of commands.

[:help z](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/index.txt.html#z) and [:help g](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/index.txt.html#g) will show you all the commands that sit behind these prefixes.

Comment: One of my favorite commands uses both g and z.  :g/pattern/z#.2

Comment: and what does that command do?

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop It finds all occurrences of `pattern`, and displays them in a list with line numbers

Comment: [Here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip227) is the description and example for usage of `g` and `z`.

Comment: That 'Power of g' article doesnt explain it, it merely demonstrates it. Explanation is wanting.