# What is the meaning of 'g'?

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode

*Note: this question has two sort of answers on StackOverflow but I thought perhaps a better answer would come from here, and, if not, at least it will be documented where it should be:*

- [What are the vim commands that start with g?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086981/what-are-the-vim-commands-that-start-with-g)
- [Use of g key in vim normal mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632472/use-of-g-key-in-vim-normal-mode)

---

What is the semantic meaning of the letter `g` in normal mode commands? I have used the heck out of `gg`, `G`, and `<n>G`, but until today, I had never thought to find out what the semantics of `g` are in the larger [Zen of Vi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1220118/9691276).

Today I had to lowercase a bunch of constants in my code, and I figured there had to be a better way than character by character (since `<n>~` doesn't work, for whatever odd reason that I am unaware of). I found it in `g~`, specifically `g~iw`.

This led me to find the linked answers, but they have less than satisfying explanations, and are on StackOverflow, and not vi.SE, to boot.

So,

#### What is the vi-semantic meaning of `g`?

By vi-semantic meaning, I expect people to understand, as `ciw` means change in word, so `c` means change, `i`, means inner text item, and `w` means word delineated by space or punctuation excluding `_`.

P.S., how do I tag this?

Comment: Relevant https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/what-does-z-stand-for-in-vim

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<kbd>g</kbd> is a little bit of a weird key in vim. A lot of other keys have a specific word to describe their category:

- `h`, `j`, `k`, `l`, `}`, `{`, `w`, `e`, etc. are all *motions*. They tell your cursor to move.
- `d`, `c`, `y`, etc. are all *operators*. They change the text they operate on in a specific way, and you tell them what text to operate on by giving a *motion*.

`g` does not have a name like this. If I had to come up with a name, I would call it a *namespace*. Bram Moolenaar and Bill Joy I'm sure had many useful operations (such as go the beginning/end of the file, or go to `[line]`) that make sense to create a shortcut for in default vim, but they're not going to be used often enough to justify giving them a one-key shortcut, since these are reserved for the more useful/frequently used things like `hjkl`, or `d` and `p`, and there's only 95 keys to pick from. [There are *tons* of keyboard shortcuts that all start with `g`.](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimindex.html#g) What do they have in common? Absolutely nothing. They just happen to be useful things to have that aren't worth giving a one-key shortcut for.

So really, `gg` is a motion just like all the other motions I listed, it just happens to use a two-key sequence. `g~` is an operator just like all the other operators I listed, it just happens to use a two-key sequence.

There are several other *"namespace"* like keys in vim. For example, look up in help

- `:h z` (Commands that start with 'z')
- `:h [` (Commands that start with '[')

Comment: So `g` is like a system leader, as opposed to a user leader. Just have to memorize the combos. Thank you.

Comment: g and z and really like namespaces for the next character. That's because we have been slowly running out of keys on a keyboard, so commands that are useful, had been added to those keys

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Yes, *namespace* is a great word for that.

Comment: I don't know that I'd group `ctrl-w` with `g`, `z`, and `[` since the former covers commands with the specific purpose of manipulating windows while the others are general "namespaces". (As evinced by their help sections having headers of the form "Commands starting with X"...`ctrl-w` falls under heading "Window commands".)

Comment: IMHO this answer should not use the word  *leader* since a leader key exists in vim and should not be confused with `g`, `z`, `[`, `]`, and `<C-w>`. I would use `namespace key` as suggested.

Comment: More importantly, `g` and `z` were two keys __not__ used in normal mode by _vi_.  Given how few keys were available, using them as prefixes for Vim-specific commands was really the only way to add a lot of new normal mode commands without resorting to chording.

Comment: "General" seems like a good mnemonic for `g`. I doubt that's properly 'semantic', but it does capture the flavor of its use as a general-purpose namespace.

Comment: Great answer. In case `CTRL-G` doesn't work due to the ruler boolean value try `g CTRL-G`. This gives detailed cursor statistics like col number, line number, word number and byte number within the file.